# T-SQL Getting Sequential events with first even criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query I am writing where I want output if a person has some service provided, then I want all the services they had provided after that and I don't want the individual returned if that is the only service they had (the criteria service)

I have some example data:
[image: sample_data]

In this instance above I would not want the last row.

The code I have, I feel is verbose at best. I am confident it works but I think it could be written better.

This will get some sample data

```sql
declare @bmh_plm_ptacct_v as table (
    med_rec_no varchar(10)
    , ptno_num varchar(10)
    , adm_date date
    , dsch_date date
    , hosp_svc varchar(5)
)

insert into @bmh_plm_ptacct_v
values('123456','123456748','2017-12-18','2018-01-12','PSY'),
('123456','123456789','2018-01-17','2018-01-18','EME'),
('123456','123456889','2018-01-19','2018-01-21','EME'),
('123456','123478978','2018-01-25','2018-01-25','EME'),
('123456','123457979','2018-05-21','2018-05-21','EME'),
('123456','123458988','2018-06-03','2018-06-04','EME'),
('123456','123458989','2018-07-27','2018-08-14','PSY'),
('123456','123458990','2018-09-23','2018-09-24','EME'),
('123456','123459999','2018-09-25','2018-09-30','PSY')

declare @vReadmits as table (
    [index] varchar(10)
    , interim int
    , [readmit] varchar(10)
)

insert into @vReadmits
values('123458990','25','123459999')

declare @hosp_svc_dim_v as table (
    hosp_svc varchar(50)
    , hosp_svc_name varchar(100)
        , orgz_cd varchar(10)
)

insert into @hosp_svc_dim_v
values('PSY','Pyschiatry','s0x0'),
('EME','Emergency Department','s0x0')
```

```sql
SELECT Med_Rec_No
, PtNo_Num
, Adm_Date
, Dsch_Date
, hosp_svc
, CASE
    WHEN B.READMIT IS NULL
    THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS [Readmit Status]
, [Event_Num] = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by med_rec_no order by ADM_date)
, [PSY_Flag] = CASE WHEN hosp_svc = 'PSY' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END

INTO #TEMPA

FROM smsdss.bmh_plm_ptacct_v AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdss.vReadmits AS B
ON A.PtNo_Num = b.[INDEX]
    AND B.INTERIM < 31

WHERE Dsch_Date >= '01-01-2018'
AND dsch_date < '12-31-2018'

ORDER BY Med_Rec_No, A.Adm_Date
;

SELECT A.*
INTO #TEMPB
FROM #TEMPA AS A
WHERE A.hosp_svc = 'PSY'
;

SELECT B.*
INTO #TEMPC
FROM #TEMPA AS B
WHERE B.hosp_svc != 'PSY'
AND B.Med_Rec_No IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Med_Rec_No
    FROM #TEMPB
)
;

SELECT Med_Rec_No
, PtNo_Num
, Adm_Date
, Dsch_Date
, hosp_svc
, [Readmit Status]
, Event_Num
, PSY_Flag
, [Keep_Flag] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MED_REC_NO ORDER BY ADM_DATE)

INTO #TEMPD

FROM (
    SELECT B.*
    FROM #TEMPB AS B

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C.*
    FROM #TEMPC AS C
    WHERE C.Med_Rec_No IN (
        SELECT ZZZ.Med_Rec_No
        FROM #TEMPB AS ZZZ
        WHERE ZZZ.Med_Rec_No = C.Med_Rec_No
        AND C.Event_Num > ZZZ.Event_Num
    )
) AS A

ORDER BY MED_REC_NO, Event_Num
;

SELECT A.Med_Rec_No
, A.PtNo_Num
, CAST(A.ADM_DATE AS DATE) AS [Adm_Date]
, CAST(A.Dsch_Date AS DATE) AS [Dsch_Date]
, A.hosp_svc
, HS.hosp_svc_name
, A.[Readmit Status]
, A.Event_Num
, A.Keep_Flag

FROM #TEMPD AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SMSDSS.hosp_svc_dim_v AS HS
ON A.hosp_svc = HS.hosp_svc
    AND HS.orgz_cd = 'S0X0'
WHERE A.Med_Rec_No IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ZZZ.MED_REC_NO
    FROM #TEMPD AS ZZZ
    WHERE Keep_Flag > 1
)

DROP TABLE #TEMPA;
DROP TABLE #TEMPB;
DROP TABLE #TEMPC;
DROP TABLE #TEMPD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Review

Your temporary table names don't say much about what they present. This makes it hard to figure out what they mean. Consider using better, more meaningful names.

> ```
> DROP TABLE #TEMPA;
> DROP TABLE #TEMPB;
> DROP TABLE #TEMPC;
> DROP TABLE #TEMPD;
> ```

It gets worse by aliasing these temporary tables with different letters:

> ```
> FROM #TEMPA AS A  -- Fair enough
>
> FROM #TEMPA AS B  -- Mamma mia!
> ```

There is only a need for an `order by` in the resulting query and the analytical functions (`row over`), not in the temporary tables.

There is no need for the temporary tables, you could use CTE's instead.

---

### Refactored Query

[Fiddle containing OP + Refactored Query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1596ba88293e9e9855b216abd2b0e109)

*This only refactors the query for readability. I am sure a more compact and optimized query could be found.*

```
with ACC as (
  SELECT Med_Rec_No
       , PtNo_Num
       , Adm_Date
       , Dsch_Date
       , hosp_svc
       , CASE WHEN B.READMIT IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [Readmit Status]
       , [Event_Num] = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by med_rec_no order by ADM_date)
       , [PSY_Flag] = CASE WHEN hosp_svc = 'PSY' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
  FROM bmh_plm_ptacct_v AS A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vReadmits AS B
  ON A.PtNo_Num = b.[INDEX] AND B.INTERIM < 31
  WHERE Dsch_Date >= '01-01-2018'
  AND dsch_date < '12-31-2018'
)
, EMERG as (
  SELECT ACC.* FROM ACC WHERE hosp_svc = 'PSY'
)
, PSY as (
  SELECT ACC.*
  FROM ACC
  WHERE hosp_svc != 'PSY'
  AND Med_Rec_No IN (SELECT DISTINCT Med_Rec_No FROM EMERG)
)
, ACC_REL as (
  SELECT Med_Rec_No
       , PtNo_Num
       , Adm_Date
       , Dsch_Date
       , hosp_svc
       , [Readmit Status]
       , Event_Num
       , PSY_Flag
       , [Keep_Flag] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MED_REC_NO ORDER BY ADM_DATE)
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM EMERG
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM PSY
    WHERE PSY.Med_Rec_No IN (
        SELECT e.Med_Rec_No
        FROM EMERG AS e
        WHERE e.Med_Rec_No = PSY.Med_Rec_No
        AND PSY.Event_Num > e.Event_Num
    )
  ) AS A
)
SELECT A.Med_Rec_No
     , A.PtNo_Num
     , CAST(A.ADM_DATE AS DATE) AS [Adm_Date]
     , CAST(A.Dsch_Date AS DATE) AS [Dsch_Date]
     , A.hosp_svc
     , HS.hosp_svc_name
     , A.[Readmit Status]
     , A.Event_Num
     , A.Keep_Flag
FROM ACC_REL AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN hosp_svc_dim_v AS HS
ON A.hosp_svc = HS.hosp_svc AND HS.orgz_cd = 'S0X0'
WHERE A.Med_Rec_No IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT rel.MED_REC_NO
    FROM ACC_REL AS rel
    WHERE Keep_Flag > 1
)
ORDER BY Med_Rec_No, Adm_Date
;
```